# Increase speed of numpy nested for loop for huge matrix

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a python code, which has nested for loop, for a huge matrix. Here rho0, alp0, bet0 are constant. and E is a symmetric matrix. How can i increase is the speed of for loop?

```
N = 20000
Q = np.zeros(shape=(N,N))               
for i in tqdm(range(0,N)):
    for j in range(0,N):
        nom    = rho0*alp0**E[i,j]*(1-alp0)**(M-E[i,j]);
        dnom   = nom + ( (1-rho0)*bet0**E[i,j]*(1-bet0)**(M-E[i,j]));
        Q[i,j] = nom/dnom;
```

Comment: PyTorch is not magic, and it's not going to speed up your code. It's a numerical computation library just like numpy.

Comment: Edited my problem statement. is there anyway the speed of loop increased?

Comment: Yes, we've each provided one way to do that. (Accidentally, the same way, about 15 second apart—it's the natural way to do it!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If everything is scalars constants except `E`, then this should work

```
    nom    = rho0*alp0**E*(1-alp0)**(M-E)
    dnom   = nom + ( (1-rho0)*bet0**E*(1-bet0)**(M-E))
    Q = nom/dnom
```

A `numpy` array `E` can be multiplied, subtracted etc as a whole.  The key to speed in `numpy` is to work with the compiled whole-array methods (and operators) where possible.  Those methods do iterate, but they do so at compiled speeds, rather than the (much) slower Python speed.

There are tools for compiling larger expressions, like `numba`, but work with the core `numpy` for a start.  Do take some time read `numpy` basics; it will save you time later.

Answer (score 1):

You can tremendously speed your code up by replacing Python looping with hardware-accelerated vector operations and tight C or Fortran loops provided by `numpy`.

(You didn't define several variables, so I took the liberty of defining them.)

```
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm

# Set these to the correct values.
rho = 0.6
alp0 = 1.4
bet0 = 2.5
M = 3.6
_E = np.random.rand(N, N)
E = _E + _E.T  # symmetric matrix.

# Look, all 20000 * 20000 values computed in one move!
nom = rho0 * alp0 ** E * (1 - alp0) ** (M - E)  # Shape is 20000x20000
dnim = nom + ((1 - rho0) * bet0 ** E * (1 - bet0) ** (M - E))  # Shape is 20000x20000
Q = nom / dnom
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. yes it improved the speed tremendously.